# Page Won't Scroll

Tags: css, scroll, web-deployment

I am making a webpage for mobile devices and the page should scroll, but is no longer scrolling. Below is all the pertinent code that should have the problem in it. Thank you for the help.

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Multi-Level Push Menu - Demo 3</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Multi-Level Push Menu: Off-screen navigation with multiple levels" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="multi-level, menu, navigation, off-canvas, off-screen, mobile, levels, nested, transform" />
        <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/icons.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="responsiveslides.css">


          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
     <script>
       $(function () {

      // Slideshow 1
      $("#slider1").responsiveSlides({
        speed: 800
      });
    });
  </script>     


        <script src="js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Push Wrapper -->
            <div class="mp-pusher" id="mp-pusher">

                <!-- mp-menu -->
                <nav id="mp-menu" class="mp-menu">
                    <div class="mp-level">
                        <h2 class="icon icon-world">All Categories</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                <a class="icon icon-display" href="#">Devices</a>
                                <div class="mp-level">
                                    <h2 class="icon icon-display">Devices</h2>
                                    <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                            <a class="icon icon-phone" href="#">Mobile Phones</a>
                                            <div class="mp-level">
                                                <h2>Mobile Phones</h2>
                                                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Super Smart Phone</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Thin Magic Mobile</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Performance Crusher</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Futuristic Experience</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                            <a class="icon icon-tv" href="#">Televisions</a>
                                            <div class="mp-level">
                                                <h2>Televisions</h2>
                                                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Flat Superscreen</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Gigantic LED</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Power Eater</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">3D Experience</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Classic Comfort</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                            <a class="icon icon-camera" href="#">Cameras</a>
                                            <div class="mp-level">
                                                <h2>Cameras</h2>
                                                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Smart Shot</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Power Shooter</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Easy Photo Maker</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#">Super Pixel</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                <a class="icon icon-news" href="#">Magazines</a>
                                <div class="mp-level">
                                    <h2 class="icon icon-news">Magazines</h2>
                                    <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">National Geographic</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Scientific American</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">The Spectator</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">The Rambler</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Physics World</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">The New Scientist</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                <a class="icon icon-shop" href="#">Store</a>
                                <div class="mp-level">
                                    <h2 class="icon icon-shop">Store</h2>
                                    <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                            <a class="icon icon-t-shirt" href="#">Clothes</a>
                                            <div class="mp-level">
                                                <h2 class="icon icon-t-shirt">Clothes</h2>
                                                <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                                        <a class="icon icon-female" href="#">Women's Clothing</a>
                                                        <div class="mp-level">
                                                            <h2 class="icon icon-female">Women's Clothing</h2>
                                                            <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Tops</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Dresses</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Trousers</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li class="icon icon-arrow-left">
                                                        <a class="icon icon-male" href="#">Men's Clothing</a>
                                                        <div class="mp-level">
                                                            <h2 class="icon icon-male">Men's Clothing</h2>
                                                            <a class="mp-back" href="#">back</a>
                                                            <ul>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Trousers</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Shoes</a></li>
                                                                <li><a href="#">Sale</a></li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="icon icon-diamond" href="#">Jewelry</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="icon icon-music" href="#">Music</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="icon icon-food" href="#">Grocery</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="icon icon-photo" href="#">Collections</a></li>
                            <li><a class="icon icon-wallet" href="#">Credits</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </nav>
                <!-- /mp-menu -->

                <div class="scroller"><!-- this is for emulating position fixed of the nav -->
                    <div class="scroller-inner">
                        <!-- Top Navigation -->
                        <div class="codrops-top clearfix">

                            <a style="width:50%;" href="#"  id="trigger"><h2><span>Menu Bar</span></h2></a>
                            <span class="right"><a href="collegemagnum.com"><h2><span>College Magnum</span></h2></a></span>
                        </div>

                <div class = "home">
                        <div class="slider_section">                            <!-- Slideshow 1 -->
                            <ul class="rslides" id="slider1">
                                 <li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                 <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                                 <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt=""></li>
                            </ul>
                            <header class="codrops-header">
                            <h1>Hello And Welcome To a New Type of Site<span>We are a website for the College Student by the Student! We have just updated to a user and device friendly interface. So please feel free to push it to the limit!</span></h1>
                            </header>
                        </div>

                        <div class="news_section">                         

                            <div>
                                <img class="news_image" src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="news_story">
                                        <span>Hello And Welcome To a New Type of Site</span>
                                        <p> Nisl adhuc moderatius pri ex. Nec melius mentitum reprimique ne. Zril efficiendi suscipiantur eum ad, mutat consequuntur usu ea. Ea usu dicam reprimique, an sit nibh ocurreret, quod incorrupte at vim. Docendi scripserit quo eu. His libris graecis ei, vitae eleifend antiopam ne est, velit mollis pro in.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <img class="news_image" src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="news_story">
                                        <span>Hello And Welcome To a New Type of Site</span>
                                        <p> Nisl adhuc moderatius pri ex. Nec melius mentitum reprimique ne. Zril efficiendi suscipiantur eum ad, mutat consequuntur usu ea. Ea usu dicam reprimique, an sit nibh ocurreret, quod incorrupte at vim. Docendi scripserit quo eu. His libris graecis ei, vitae eleifend antiopam ne est, velit mollis pro in.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <img class="news_image" src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="news_story">
                                        <span>Hello And Welcome To a New Type of Site</span>
                                        <p> Nisl adhuc moderatius pri ex. Nec melius mentitum reprimique ne. Zril efficiendi suscipiantur eum ad, mutat consequuntur usu ea. Ea usu dicam reprimique, an sit nibh ocurreret, quod incorrupte at vim. Docendi scripserit quo eu. His libris graecis ei, vitae eleifend antiopam ne est, velit mollis pro in.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <img class="news_image" src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="news_story">
                                        <span>Hello And Welcome To a New Type of Site</span>
                                        <p> Nisl adhuc moderatius pri ex. Nec melius mentitum reprimique ne. Zril efficiendi suscipiantur eum ad, mutat consequuntur usu ea. Ea usu dicam reprimique, an sit nibh ocurreret, quod incorrupte at vim. Docendi scripserit quo eu. His libris graecis ei, vitae eleifend antiopam ne est, velit mollis pro in.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <img class="news_image" src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
                                <div class="news_story">
                                        <span>Hello And Welcome To a New Type of Site</span>
                                        <p> Nisl adhuc moderatius pri ex. Nec melius mentitum reprimique ne. Zril efficiendi suscipiantur eum ad, mutat consequuntur usu ea. Ea usu dicam reprimique, an sit nibh ocurreret, quod incorrupte at vim. Docendi scripserit quo eu. His libris graecis ei, vitae eleifend antiopam ne est, velit mollis pro in.</p>
                                </div>

                            </div>


                        </div>
                </div>  


                    </div><!-- /scroller-inner -->
                </div><!-- /scroller -->

            </div><!-- /pusher -->
        </div><!-- /container -->
        <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
        <script src="js/mlpushmenu.js"></script>
        <script>
            new mlPushMenu( document.getElementById( 'mp-menu' ), document.getElementById( 'trigger' ) );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the css:

```
    *,
*:after,
*::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, .container, .scroller {
    height: 100%;
}


.home{
width: auto;
height: auto;
overflow:hidden;

}

.slider_section{
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: auto;

}

.news_section{
width: 50%;
float: right;
overflow:auto;
height: auto;
}

.news_image{
width: 45%;
height: 175px;
float: left;
}

.news_story{
width: 55%;
height: 175px;
padding: 5px;
float: right;
overflow:auto;
    font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
    padding: .5em;
        margin: 0;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    line-height: 1.3;
}

.news_story p {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: .5em;
        margin: 0;
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: .65em;
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.news_story span {
text-decoration:underline;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-align:center;
}


}


.scroller {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.scroller,
.scroller-inner {
    position: relative;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0, #1D78EF),
    color-stop(1, #5BCBFF)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #1D78EF 0%, #5BCBFF 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #1D78EF 0%, #5BCBFF 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #1D78EF 0%, #5BCBFF 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #1D78EF 0%, #5BCBFF 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1D78EF 0%, #5BCBFF 100%);
}

.menu-trigger {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 60px;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}

.menu-trigger:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 40px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 6px #34495e, 0 12px #fff, 0 18px #34495e, 0 24px #fff;
    content: '';
}

.mp-pusher {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.mp-menu {
    position: absolute; /* we can't use fixed here :( */
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.mp-level {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0, #1D63F0),
    color-stop(0.4, #303030)
);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #1D63F0 0%, #303030 40%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1D63F0 0%, #303030 40%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1D63F0 0%, #303030 40%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1D63F0 0%, #303030 40%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1D63F0 0%, #303030 40%);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

/* overlays for pusher and for level that gets covered */
.mp-pusher::after,
.mp-level::after,
.mp-level::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: '';
    opacity: 0;
}

.mp-pusher::after,
.mp-level::after {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, width 0.1s 0.3s, height 0.1s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, width 0.1s 0.3s, height 0.1s 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, width 0.1s 0.3s, height 0.1s 0.3s;
}

.mp-level::after {
    z-index: -1;
}

.mp-pusher.mp-pushed::after,
.mp-level.mp-level-overlay::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.mp-level.mp-level-overlay {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.mp-level.mp-level-overlay.mp-level::before {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 1;
}

.mp-pusher,
.mp-level {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

/* overlap */
.mp-overlap .mp-level.mp-level-open {
    box-shadow: 1px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-40px, 0, 0);
}

/* First level */
.mp-menu > .mp-level,
.mp-menu > .mp-level.mp-level-open,
.mp-menu.mp-overlap > .mp-level,
.mp-menu.mp-overlap > .mp-level.mp-level-open {
    box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

/* cover */
.mp-cover .mp-level.mp-level-open {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.mp-cover .mp-level.mp-level-open > ul > li > .mp-level:not(.mp-level-open) {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

/* content style */
.mp-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.mp-menu h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #F7F7F7;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.mp-menu.mp-overlap h2::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 8px;
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 1.8;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.1s 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.1s 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.1s 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.mp-menu.mp-cover h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.mp-overlap .mp-level.mp-level-overlay > h2::before {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.mp-menu ul li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0.7em 1em 0.7em 1.8em;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    font-size: 1.4em;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s, box-shadow 0.3s;
}

.mp-menu ul li::before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    line-height: 3.5;
}

.mp-level > ul > li:first-child > a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), inset 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.mp-menu ul li a:hover,
.mp-level > ul > li:first-child > a:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.mp-menu .mp-level.mp-level-overlay > ul > li > a,
.mp-level.mp-level-overlay > ul > li:first-child > a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.mp-back {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    padding: 1em;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s;
    transition: background 0.3s;
}

.mp-back::after {
    font-family: 'linecons';
    position: absolute;
    content: "\e037";
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.mp-menu .mp-level.mp-level-overlay > .mp-back,
.mp-menu .mp-level.mp-level-overlay > .mp-back::after {
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: transparent;
}

/* Fallback example for browsers that don't support 3D transforms (and no JS fallback) */
/* We'll show the first level only */
.no-csstransforms3d .mp-pusher,
.no-js .mp-pusher {
    padding-left: 300px;
}

.no-csstransforms3d .mp-menu .mp-level,
.no-js .mp-menu .mp-level {
    display: none;
}

.no-csstransforms3d .mp-menu > .mp-level,
.no-js .mp-menu > .mp-level {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method .responsiveSlides is called which is from responsiveslides.min.js, you have to post this and see what the script to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
    html, body, .container, .scroller {
    height: 100%;
}
```

from your CSS, and it will scroll fully.

The code I'm telling you to remove sets a fixed *width* and *height* on the **body,** so it can't scroll larger than the browser's height (100%).

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the outer div's Width/Height some fixed value.So that when the inner Div's Content is overlapping then Scroll will come as setting "Overflow:auto" property for outer Div's class.

You can try giving some fixed height/width like Windows height or width to the outermost div and then overflow the content of inner div should get you the Scroll if "Overflow:auto" style property is defined.

Hope this helps.